# I have a theme node in my response object, why can't I access it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm calling a local service that calls a remote service and returns an object like this back:

[image]

but If I try to set my scope variable to it, it keeps saying undefined? Here are the two different ways I've tried.

```
themefactory.then(function (data) {
      $scope.themeObject = data.theme;
      $scope.themeObj = angular.fromJson(data.theme);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `data.Data.theme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
themefactory.then(function (data) {
      $scope.themeObject = data.Data.theme;
};
```

Comment: I should have called my response 'response' instead of 'data', then I would have seen this right away. Thanks for pointing that out!